# Test a Ping for server in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How to create a simple script to test the ping in Jenkins? I am trying to test a server and check the ping of that server using Jenkins shall script
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
You can put the below lines in a shell script and update the server_ip you want to ping against

server_ip="add your IP here"
SYS_PING=`ping -c 5 ${server_ip} | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{print \$2}'`
echo "Pinging ${server_ip} with response: "${SYS_PING}" "


output : 
1. ping success message : "Pinging **server_ip** with response: 5 received"

2. ping failure message : "Pinging **server_ip** with response: 0 received"
```

Comment: it gives me error unexpected char: '`' @ line 8, column 26.
                   SYS_PING=`ping -c 5 ${server_ip} | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{print \$2}'`

Comment: The code in the answer works for me. It differs from that in your comment by the ` symbol beween = and ping, line 2.
Maybe you need a shebang? aka #!/bin/bash